# Group rows by date and overwrite NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe of the following structure which is simplified for this question.

```
  A          B   C   D   E
0 2014/01/01 nan nan 0.2 nan
1 2014/01/01 0.1 nan nan nan 
2 2014/01/01 nan 0.3 nan 0.7
3 2014/01/02 nan 0.4 nan nan
4 2014/01/02 0.5 nan 0.6 0.8
```

What I have here is a series of readings across several timestamps on single days. The columns B,C,D and E represent different locations. The data I am reading in is set up such that at a specified timestamp it takes data from certain locations and fills in nan values for the other locations.

What I wish to do is group the data by timestamp which I can easily do with a `.GroupBy()`command. From there I wish to have the nan values in the grouped data be overwritten with the valid values taken in later rows such that this is the following result is obtained.

```
  A          B   C   D   E
0 2014/01/01 0.1 0.3 0.2 0.7
1 2014/01/02 0.5 0.4 0.6 0.8
```

How do I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `df.groupby` with `DataFrameGroupBy.agg`:

```
In [528]: df.groupby('A', as_index=False, sort=False).agg(np.nansum)
Out[528]: 
            A    B    C    D    E
0  2014/01/01  0.1  0.3  0.2  0.7
1  2014/01/02  0.5  0.4  0.6  0.8
```

---

A shorter version with [`DataFrameGroupBy.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#groupby-sorting) (thanks MaxU!):

```
In [537]: df.groupby('A', as_index=False, sort=False).sum()
Out[537]: 
            A    B    C    D    E
0  2014/01/01  0.1  0.3  0.2  0.7
1  2014/01/02  0.5  0.4  0.6  0.8
```

Comment: why do we need `np.nansum`? `df.groupby('A', as_index=False, sort=False).sum()` - should do the trick...

Comment: @MaxU Brilliant. Wasn't sure sum() took nans into account. I'm still learning so welcome your comments :)

Comment: Excellent answer. Link to Pandas docs here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#groupby-sorting

Comment: i think can simple use `first` :)

Answer (score 2):

you can try this by using `pandas` `first`

```
df.groupby('A', as_index=False).first()


          A    B    C    D    E
0  1/1/2014  0.1  0.3  0.2  0.7
1  1/2/2014  0.5  0.4  0.6  0.8
```